# Overriding tabs style in material-ui (no left/right padding)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to override padding n tabs, so that the indicator is the same length as text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzYjy.png

I was playing with this example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/o4wp31yo95
... without any luck. I need to remove left/right padding from buttonbase but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your styles:

```
labelContainer: {
    padding: 0,
},
```

And then add it to you `<Tab>` components. Like:

```
classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected, labelContainer: classes.labelContainer }}
```

This will make the indicator the same length as the text, but only for texts longer that 72 pixels, because of the `minWidth: 72` on `tabRoot`. To make it work for smaller texts also make this value smaller.

Comment: Works when I try it.